# Android Studio - keyboard with caps lock every new word

Tags: android, android-studio, keyboard

I want to set my keyboard to a keyboard that every new word, will cap lock the first letter.

Like:
`This Is An Example`

And not:

`This is an example`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `EditText` fields, you just have to add:

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:inputType="textCapWords"
    ....
/>
```

in the XML file.

Or programmatically use:

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS)
```